# How to change boot picture in Windows 10 IoT?

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi2, iot, windowsondevices

Is it possible to change the Windows logo during boot in `Raspberry Pi 2` with `Windows 10 IoT` core?

My goal is to show just a splashscreen until the application is loading. I don't want to show Windows logo, but black screen is also bad idea (because of no feedback).
In Windows 8/10 tablets I have seen branded boot screen, so it is possible there, but not sure how to achieve this in Windows 10 IoT.

According to [Unbranded Boot Overview (Windows Embedded Standard 8)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj963199(v=winembedded.81).aspx):

> The only supported way to replace the boot logo in Standard 8 with a custom logo is to modify the Boot Graphics Resource Table (BGRT) on a device that uses UEFI as the firmware interface. If your device uses the BGRT to include a custom logo, it is always displayed, and Unbranded Boot cannot suppress the custom logo.

I know it is for Windows Embedded, but that is the closest article I found about branding.

I don't know how the Raspberry Pi 2 booting works and whether it has UEFI or what. I guess it is at lower level.

Comment: Are we talking about the splash screen of the rPi2? The Raspberry Pi boot and other embedded systems are different. I am not aware of an easy way to do this in Linux, so it is fairly unlikely many people have learned how to do it with Windows yet, if its different at all.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Processes page on the IoT Utilities page and type these commands. It should disable the Windows logo.

```
1 - bcdedit /set quietboot on
2 - bcdedit /set bootux Disabled
3 - bcdedit /set bootuxdisabled on
```

Then restart `RPI`

Comment: Thanks, but your code completely disables the boot screen. I found that to achieve this it is enough to use only the last command `bcdedit /set bootuxdisabled on`. But I want to see the progress ring (just not the Windows logo) or replace that windows logo with a custom picture.

Answer (score 0):

For future Googlers, if you want to keep the spinner but lose the windows logo on Win10 IOT, run the following bcdedit command:

```
bcdedit /set {globalsettings} custom:16000067 true
```